# How to hide current form in Load()

Tags: c#, winforms, load

I have an EULA form, this is the first form to be shown. Though if a user ticks a checkBox my program creates a hidden txt file in the same directory. On program start if the file exists I don't want the EULA form to be shown but the main `Form1`.

```
private void EULA_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    string file = path + "EULA.txt";
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        this.Hide();
        var form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        form1.Show();
     }
}
```

On `ButtonClick` I could use the code within the if clause above successfully.

The code above opens both the `EULA` and `Form1`. Why?

EDIT:
I tried it in `Program.cs` in `Main()` as advised:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        string file = path + "Mailer_EULA.txt";
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new EULA());
        }
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
    }
```

But this opens `Form1` whether the file exists or not.

Comment: why not do the check on `static void Main()` in the Program class?

Comment: Because until this very moment I did not know that is possible. :) Let me check that.

Comment: If you add your code on the shown event of the form you get the desired outcome. But I don't think this is the correct place to do this. So try the Program class.

Comment: are you sure you don't have the original `Application.Run(new Form1());` code below somewhere?

Comment: 100% sure, I copied the whole `Main()`.

Comment: and you are sure the text file is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the check on `static void Main()` in the Program class?

Try this:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        string file = Path.Combine(path, "EULA.txt");
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            var form1 = new Form1();
            form1.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
            form1.Show();
        }
        else 
        {
            var eula = new EULA();
            eula.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` does not exist in `Main()`. So I did something else. Please check my question, there is an update.

Comment: Always use Path.Combine(), helps you avoid the standard bug of forgetting to put a backslash before the filename.

Comment: OMG. I did not put the backslash between the path and the filename. Hans Passant is right. So I thought I deleted the file, but not. Though you solved my issue Tjaart van der Walt, thank you.